# Power BI: Conditional Formating Matrix Visual with data bars

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would like to create a matrix visual like below and add data bars as conditional formating to the "`Sales Percentage`" Column with different user defined max and min values based on the countries.

**I have the following dummy data**

| Salesperson | Country | Product | Sales Percentage | Total Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gina | Canada | City Bike | 0.02 | 232 |
| Gina | Canada | Mountain Bike | 0.56 | 2800 |
| Gina | Italy | City Bike | 0.32 | 213 |
| Gina | Italy | Mountain Bike | 0.21 | 1050 |
| Gina | USA | City Bike | 0.11 | 122 |
| Gina | USA | Mountain Bike | 0.43 | 2150 |
| John | Canada | City Bike | 0.32 | 333 |
| John | Canada | Mountain Bike | 0.34 | 442 |
| John | Italy | City Bike | 0.12 | 2132 |
| John | Italy | Mountain Bike | 0.67 | 1233 |
| John | USA | City Bike | 0.22 | 3300 |
| John | USA | Mountain Bike | 0.45 | 7300 |
| Mary | Canada | City Bike | 0.21 | 121 |
| Mary | Canada | Mountain Bike | 0.53 | 2650 |
| Mary | Italy | City Bike | 0.32 | 213 |
| Mary | Italy | Mountain Bike | 0.12 | 600 |
| Mary | USA | City Bike | 0.11 | 123 |
| Mary | USA | Mountain Bike | 0.12 | 600 |

The matrix looks like this after showing columns as rows and putting "`Sales Percentage`" and "`Total Sales`" as values, Country as columns and `Product + Salesperson` as rows:

[image]

I can add databars when I right click the Sales Percentage under values but I can only enter one user defined min and max value for the whole "`Sales Percentage`" column. Is it possible to have different maximum value for data bars based on the Country? For example to create a target value of `35% for Canada`, `40% for USA` and `50% for Italy`. So in other words the data bar would be full when the Sales Percentage for Canada reaches 35% and full when Sales Percentage for USA reaches 40% and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible with you current setup. The best you could do to approximate this is as follows.

Create a measure as follows:

```
% Canada = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Total Sales]), 'Table'[Country ] = "Canada")
```

Do the same for USA and Italy and then add them as values to your matrix.

[image]

[image]

You can now select individual targets for each country.